# Vanilla javascript in custom gutenberg block not working

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I am trying to create a custom gutenberg block for a school project. I am new to this and I have not used the @wordpress/create-block method. I have created a plugin with a test block manually with a php-, css and javascript file. The javascript uses wp.element.createElement methods to generate the block in the edit and save functions. Everything works there.

The php plugin file:

```
 <?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Javascriptblock
 * Description: JS Test
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: Test
 */

if (!defined("ABSPATH")) {
    exit;
}

function javascriptblock() {

    wp_register_script(
        "js-script",
        plugins_url("js.js", __FILE__),
        array("wp-blocks", "wp-components", "wp-element", "wp-i18n", "wp-editor"),
        filemtime(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "js.js")
    );

    wp_register_style(
        "js-style",
        plugins_url("/js.css", __FILE__),
        array("wp-edit-blocks"),
        filemtime(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . "js.css")
    );

    register_block_type("javascriptblock/js", array(
        "editor_script" => "js-script",
        "editor_style"  => "js-style",
        "style"         => "js-style",
        "category"      => "common",
    ));
}
add_action("init", "javascriptblock");
```

And the javascript:

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockType("javascriptblock/javascriptblock", {
    title: "Javascriptblock",
    icon: "smiley",
    category: "common",
  
    edit: function () {
        return wp.element.createElement(
            "p",
            null,
            "Hello World"
        );
    },
  
    save: function () {
        function Test() {
            console.log("It works!");
        }
  
        console.log("Save function has been run!");

        Test();

        return wp.element.createElement(
            "p",
            null,
            "Hello World!"
        );
    },
});
```

As you can see I have tried to use console log both in a function and by itself. Nothing shows in the console when I generate the block on the frontend.

End goal is to make some kind of animation for images in the block using javascript.

How can I execute vanilla javascript functions within my block? Using Wordpress 6.2.

I have tried to console log "Test" in the beginning, middle and end of the save function. Not working.
The php plugin file that contains the block javascript has it registered using wp_register_script. I have also tried wp_enqueue_script. All the code in the block works fine except vanilla javascript functions.

Comment: There is a [wordpress.stackexchange.com](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=execute+javascript) site

Comment: Please show the scripts (Javascript / PHP) you tried.

Comment: I would try working with a ``block.json`` file, it's gonna make your life quite a bit easier.